# Azure Blob + Cloudflare CDN = SSL Issues

Tags: dns, azure-blob-storage, cloudflare, blobstorage

I'm following a few different guides, but the gist is being able to host some static HTML pages using Azure blob storage. Starting I used [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal) to set up the blob for web content.

Then followed up by using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal) to add my custom domain name.

We use Cloudflare for our DNS, and I created the CNAME record for the static webpage, as directed in guide 2. In Azure, when 'verifying' the domain, you can't have the CNAME record 'proxied' in Cloudflare. As soon as we 'verify' the domain/subdomain, the content is live, however, you get an SSL error when trying to browse the content with the custom domain.

[image]

If I enable 'proxying' on the CNAME record, I then get this message:

[image]

So I'm at a loss as to what exactly to do here.

Answer (score 0):

> The requested content does not exist. HttpStatusCode: 404.

The error code you mentioned indicates that the server is unable to locate the resource requested by the client.

- To fix this issue, you need to change your access level to either container (anonymous read access for container and blob) or blob (anonymous read access for blobs only).
- If you want to access the files of a static website through the static website endpoint (e.g. [account.z5.web.core.windows.net](http://account.z5.web.core.windows.net)), you don’t have to modify the Access Control List (ACL) of the blob container. The files should be accessible even if the ACL of $web is set to Private. However, if you access the content through the blob storage endpoint (e.g [account.blob.core.windows.net](http://account.blob.core.windows.net)), then the ACL of the blob container becomes important.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[STATIC WEBSITE NOT WORKING - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/696299/static-website-not-working) by Sumarigo-MSFT.